# Fiori : Could not open App

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, sap-web-ide

I am implementing Manage Journal Entries App in S/4Hana 1610 (App ID : F0717 as per Fiori App Library) and followed the guide given in the Fiori App Library.

When I click on it ,encounters [Console error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBwtP.png) , [Console error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAFD1.png) .
i.e.

> Error: failed to load 'sap/ssuite/fnd/om/outputcontrol/library.js'

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is still looking for this error.

The resolution is to Activate SICF Service FND_OM_OUT_CLS1(Pre-requisite for this service is software component UIS4HOP1 200 SP 0000 to be installed in your FrontEnd Server).

Regards,

Rehan Sayed